# Save multiple Items many-to-many Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, relationship

I'm trying to save multiple `Product` into `Purchase` by using `Vuejs` for frontend and `Laravel` for `Backend` and that is a `many-to-many` relationship between them.

`In My Vuejs`

```
   <tr class="tablePurchase--td" v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.code}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="table-quantity" v-model="items[index].quantity">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="table-quantity" v-model="items[index].unit_price" placeholder="0.00">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="table-quantity" v-model="items[index].discount" placeholder="0.00">
        </td>
        <td>
            <v-btn small color="red" outlined @click="removeItem(index)">
                <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

`In my Controller`

```
    public funtion store(Request $request) {
        ....

        foreach($purchase->products as $item) {
            $purchase->products()->attach($product_id, [
                'unit_price' => $item['unit_price'],
                'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
                'discount' => $item['discount'],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

But, its got empty array... i even tried `dd($request->items)` and its return `null`

I'll appreciate all ur Help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should name all of your inputs as `items[]`

```
//...
<input type="number" class="table-quantity" name="items[]" v-model="items[index].unit_price" placeholder="0.00">
//...
```

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: What did dd($request->all()) return ?

Comment: how can i share it with u?

Comment: I replied to you